# How do I make ⌘← and ⌘→ work for home/end combo for Terminal?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, keyboard, terminal

Why does <kbd>fn</kbd>-<kbd>⇧</kbd>-<kbd>→</kbd> (or others) do a home/end in Terminal but a <kbd>⌘</kbd>-<kbd>→</kbd> works everywhere else?

So just to be clear the question is how to make Terminal take <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>←</kbd> and <kbd>→</kbd> for home and end?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

As convenient as it would be, Terminal can't easily provide the functionality you ask for.

The reason is that programs that run inside Terminal have different rules for moving the cursor to the beginning/end of the line, for example:

- `bash` (and other shells) use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>E</kbd>
- `vi` uses <kbd>0</kbd> and <kbd>$</kbd>/<kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>4</kbd>

Other programs may use other keys. **There isn't a universal key combination for positioning the cursor at the beginning/end of the line.**

Of course, Terminal could maintain a list of key combinations for a number of common programs, check what's running and send the correct keys for you, or it could provide a menu item like *Move Cursor To Beginning Of Line Inside Shell ⌘←* and then send <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> behind the scenes. But I guess Apple engineers thought that if you venture in [CLI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command-line_interface) territory you know its idiosyncrasies.

As a side note, Terminal provides <kbd>Option</kbd><kbd>←</kbd> and <kbd>Option</kbd><kbd>→</kbd> which behaves in `bash` as you would expect and moves the cursor to the beginning of the previous/next word. That's because these key combinations are mapped to <kbd>Esc</kbd><kbd>b</kbd> and <kbd>Esc</kbd><kbd>b</kbd> (see `man bash`, section "Commands for Moving" for more information). In `vi`, for example, only the latter (kind of) works (at the end of this answer I'll show how to configure `vi` to work with <kbd>Option</kbd><kbd>←</kbd> and <kbd>Option</kbd><kbd>→</kbd>).

**But thanks to Automator, AppleScript and bash aliases you can get <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>←</kbd> and <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>→</kbd> to work with `bash` (and possibly other shells) and `vi`.**

The first step is to map <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>←</kbd> and <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>→</kbd> to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>E</kbd>. In a second step, I'll show you how to configure `vi` to honor <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>E</kbd> (which, as a result, will make `vi` compatible with <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>←</kbd> and <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>→</kbd>).

**Map <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>←</kbd> and <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>→</kbd> to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>E</kbd>**

1. In Terminal, go to Preferences...>Settings>[your active profile]>Keyboard:
   [image]
2. Press <kbd>+</kbd>, select "Cursor Left", "Control-Shift" as modifier and action "Send Text:". Then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> (`\001` will appear in the text field) and confirm with <kbd>OK</kbd>:
   [image]

   (In a previous version of this answer I used "Shift" as a modifier. I've noticed that this setting conflicts with <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>shift</kbd><kbd>←</kbd>, which shows the previous Terminal tab, if you don't let go of <kbd>⌘</kbd> immediately. Using "Control-Shift" fixes that.)
3. Now add a key combination for "Cursor Right", but  press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>E</kbd> (`\005` will appear in the text field). Confirm with <kbd>OK</kbd>.
4. Open Automator (for example, hit <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>space</kbd> to bring up Spotlight and type *Automator*), select File>New and choose `Service`:

   [image]
5. Drag `Run AppleScript` to the right pane:
   [image]
6. Type the following script:

   ```
   on run {input, parameters}
       tell application "System Events"
           tell application process "Terminal"
               key code 123 using {shift down, control down}
           end tell
       end tell
   end run
   ```

   and save as `Move Cursor to Beginning of Line`:

   [image]
7. Repeat steps 4. to 6. with this script:

   ```
   on run {input, parameters}
       tell application "System Events"
           tell application process "Terminal"
               key code 124 using {shift down, control down}
           end tell
       end tell
   end run
   ```

   and save as `Move Cursor to End of Line`:

   [image]
8. This is what Terminal>Services looks like now:

   [image]

**Configure `vi` to honor <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>E</kbd>**

1. Open `.bashrc` with your favorite editor and add this line:

   `alias vi='vim -c "map <C-A> 0" -c "map <C-E> $" -c "map <Esc>b B" -c "map <Esc>f E"'`

   The first two `map` commands tell `vim` to interpret <kbd>Control</kbd><kbd>E</kbd> and <kbd>Control</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> as <kbd>$</kbd> and <kbd>0</kbd>, which move the cursor to the beginning or end of line, respectively.

   The last two `map` commands tell `vim` to move the cursor one word at a time as you would expect when pressing <kbd>option</kbd><kbd>←</kbd> and <kbd>Option</kbd><kbd>→</kbd>.

**Caveats**

You will notice that there is a short delay between the moment you press <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>←</kbd> or <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>→</kbd> and the moment the cursor actually moves.

Bear in mind that it will only work for programs that honor <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>A</kbd>/<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>E</kbd>, so you may still want to learn the specific key combinations of each program you use in Terminal.

(Tested on macOS Sierra 10.12.4)

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer, is there a petition to just have Apple include a home/end button on the next redesign :-)

Comment: I'm glad I could help.

Comment: Wow.. all this to get a freaking `⌘` shortcut

Comment: This is a good answer, but it could be improved by excluding all the extraneous information about `vi` which is a completely different application than the terminal.

Comment: Oh if apple would just give us a normal keyboard!

Comment: @axiopisty The reason I mention `vi` is because it is a program that I expect people to use when running Terminal.app and that needs a special tweak to work with the <Cmd>-<arrow> combo. Other CLI programs, like `emacs`, support Ctrl-A and Ctrl-E and thus don't need any special configuration. Anyway, I don't understand your point about `vi`, the other program I mention,`bash`, is *also* a completely different application than the terminal (Terminal.app)...

Comment: That is a great trick. I also managed to get the AppleScript running by sending the keycodes for "Home" and "End": "key code 115"  and "key code 119""

Answer (score 2):

Of course its possible.

First of all, you can use the free tool "DoubleCommand" if you have a windows keyboard with HOME/END keys to make'em behave like they should (beginning /end of line).

Secondly, for terminal specifically, go to the preferences, Keyboard, edit the icon/key which looks like an arrow pointing up-left, select "send text" and type ctrl+a. Done!

Same for the end button..

If you dont have a PC keyboard, you can do the same with other key combinations.